# Ошибка в python, библиотека PyQt5: ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebKitWidgets'

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.6

Недавно я начал изучать библиотеку `PyQt5` (версия 5.14.2)
 и решил написать свой браузер. Я сделал интерфейс в дизайнере и превратил это в python файл. В этом файле у меня и возникла данная ошибка.

Я уже узнал, что ошибка происходит из за того, что эта библиотека уже устарела и удалена, но как мне исправить код и заменить эту библиотеку на новую, чтобы всё работало так же? Вот код(python 3.6):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'bro22.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(593, 397)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 30, 351, 25))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 30, 41, 25))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"background-color:red;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 254, 31))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 591, 21))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 591, 20))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 67, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.webView = QtWebKitWidgets.QWebView(self.centralwidget)
        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 591, 291))
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("about:blank"))
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 593, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "serch"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">>>"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "rm"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SBrowser"))
from PyQt5 import QtWebKitWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from PyQt5 import QtWebKitWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(593, 397)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 30, 351, 25))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 30, 41, 25))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"background-color:red;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 254, 31))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 591, 21))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 591, 20))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 67, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
###
#        self.webView = QtWebKitWidgets.QWebView(self.centralwidget)
        self.webView = QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget)                        # +++


        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 591, 291))
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("about:blank"))
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 593, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "serch"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">>>"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "rm"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SBrowser"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам, но у меня теперь возникла новая ошибка:     ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(search)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPushButton has been deleted
Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Comment: 1.  вы спрашивали: `как мне исправить код и заменить эту библиотеку на новую`, я вам ответил. Если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, не забудьте отметить мой ответ как правильный.  2. Если у вас возникают другие ошибки, вы должны открыть НОВЫЙ вопрос, описать, что вы хотите сделать, что у вас не получается и приложить пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: хорошо, буду знать.